# keep getting ".getSelected is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

i've made an HtmlTable.Select in mootools 1.3 of an existing table, tried "selectable: true" and "enableSelect", nothing works, if i try to access the "getSelected"-method of my table, i keep getting ".getSelected is not a function", all other functions like "selectAll" or "selectNone" work perfectly".

my code (from inside my class):

```
this.options.HTMLTable = new HtmlTable(this.options.table, {
    selectable : true
});

// this works perfect ...  
this.options.HTMLTable.selectAll();

// ... but this causes the error!  
console.log(this.options.HTMLTable.getSelected());
```

can you help?

Comment: try `console.dir(this.options.HTMLTable)`

Comment: thank you, but it hast nothing to do with the console, even if i write var x = table.getSelected(); i'm getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a mooTools expert but if you check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/Vn2b5/)

You will see that in the prototype (`.__proto__`) of `this.options.HTMLTable` the method `selectAll` is defined but `getSelected` is not.

This is a start to your debugging. Add some data to the fiddle to make it more realistic of your issue.

There's a `._selectedRows` property on HTMLTable though. just write your own .getSelected method and be done with it!

I just read the source code and the method `getSelected` doesn't exist. Here's what it should do

```
function getSelected() {
    return this._selectedRows;
}
```

File it as a bug and in the meanwhile just use

```
// Bug in HtmlTable. Custom implementation. Remove when using mootools 1.4
HtmlTable = new Class({
    Extends: HtmlTable, 
    getSelected: function() {
        return this._selectedRows;
    }
});
```

As @DimitarChristoff recommended your better off using:

```
if (!HtmlTable.prototype.getSelected) {
    HtmlTable.prototype.getSelected = function() {
        return this._selectedRows;
    };      
}
```

This way you only change the prototype of HtmlTable if it's neccessary. You might need some kind of HtmlTable.Select is loaded check.

See new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/cujNP/11/)

Comment: thank you very much, i wrote a basic setup of my situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/philippdatz/cujNP/10/ , but even in this case the error occurs. has this function simply forgotten by the mootools-team?

Comment: @philippdatz feels like something went horribly wrong. Wouldn't file it as amootools bug just yet

Comment: solved it. found it here in the mootools lighthouse repo: https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/24057/tickets/477-missing-getselected-method and write the method for my own, as here https://github.com/subhaze/mootools-more/commit/3c4eb7efa827b5878957f34abcb5d9a8aae2f28c and as @raynos sayd, thank you all!

Comment: @philippdatz yes it does indeed seem to be a bug. Thankfully someone has already filed and fixed it for you.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but doing `var myClass = new Class({extends: myClass});` feels wrong and wasteful to me. Either modify the class prototype directly or use `Class.refactor(myClass, {... })`. http://jsfiddle.net/Vn2b5/1/ with the former method.

Comment: in fact, to improve on the fix above w/o editing mootools-more direct and non-breaking if / when the fix goes through, you should check for the existing prototype first: http://jsfiddle.net/Vn2b5/2/ - that way at a later date when new mootools-more is dropped in and / or the internal api changes, you won't have to change any code eg, `_selectedRows` is no longer available

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Thank you I havn't really used mootools. Indeed appending to the prototype if it's not there is the most ideal. Could you suggest some kind of if HtmlTable.Select is loaded check?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vn2b5/4/ can do it. basically if it fails to find the selectRange (and notice i mistype it as jsfiddle has it), it will lazy load the latest ver from github (which is async hence the function callback). basic assumption here is that the main HtmlTable class is loaded, though.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I meant that the example would append `.getSelected` even if you don't want to use `HtmlTable.Select` extension to `HtmlTable`. So it should only append `.getSelected` if its loaded. Rather then load it if its not loaded

Comment: Ah, I get it - you don't want to alter the prototype if Select has not been loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/Vn2b5/6/ via any of the unique methods defined https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Interface/HtmlTable.Select.js, it ought to be fine.

Comment: Instead of setting directly on the prototype, I would use `HtmlTable.implement`